# rCharts - Hide all series EXCEPT selected series from legend

Tags: javascript, r, rcharts

I like to do the reversal of the default logic. When I click on a series in the legend, I would like to hide all series except the selected one. I know I have to use JS for this. The solutions I found did not work for me.

I found [this](https://jsfiddle.net/t2MxW/21971/) solution but when I modify my code for R like this:

```
legendItemClick = "#! function(event) {
        if (!this.visible)
        return false;

        var seriesIndex = this.index;
        var series = this.chart.series;

        for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++)
        {
        if (series[i].index != seriesIndex)
        {
        series[i].visible ?
        series[i].hide() :
        series[i].show();
        } 
        }
        return false;
  } !#"
```

However, that does not work and no plot is showing at all. How do I have to modify the code from fiddle so it works within R using rChart/Highcharts?

Comment: Okay, I solved the problem. I had to put this into `plot$series(event = ...)`. and not into `plot$plotOptions`